# Invalid Layer Arn Error when using ARN value from SSM parameters

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

Lambda layer ARN is stored in SSM parameter and need to access the value of this parameter to put as an Layer arn while defining a function and attaching a layer to it.

ERROR: SayHelloLayerARN is an Invalid Layer Arn.

Parameter Name in Parameter Store: SayHelloLayerARN

Here is the SAM template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  CREATE-WITH-SSM

  Sample SAM Template for CREATE-WITH-SSM

Parameters:
  HelloLayerARN:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: SayHelloLayerARN
    Description: Layer ARN from SSM

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LAYER_NAME: !Ref HelloLayerARN
      Layers:
        - !Ref HelloLayerARN
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
```

Comment: Yes, SAM was not able to resolve the SSM Parameters, Just because I was using sam cli version 1.17, In the later version of SAM this problem has been resolved. I upgraded my SAM cli to 1.36 and its working correctly. Thanks @user17589914 and virenstack for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, SAM doesn't resolve SSM parameters.

Please try using --parameter-overrides option

Example: sam build --parameter-overrides HelloLayerARN=LambdaLayerARN

Note: You must change the HelloLayerARN Type to normal String, other sam deploy fails with SSM parameter resolving error.

```
Parameters:
  HelloLayerARN:
    Type: String #AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: SayHelloLayerARN
    Description: Layer ARN from SSM
```

Please refer the known issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1069

Answer (score 0):

The --parameter-overrides solution mentioned by @user17589914 works for build and deploy but it does not work for local invoke (I will be very happy to be proven wrong). Below are some details on my findings and workaround:

The layers specific issue aside, there is an open issue with inconsistency between --env-vars vs --parameter-overrides for build, deploy and local invoke, just FYI.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1163

So in general, I am using --env-vars for local invoke with dev parameters defined in a json file. And for build & deploy, I use the --parameter-overrides with parameters for multiple envs defined in a samconfig.toml.

For the Layer ARN reference not working issue, I have not been able to get local invoke to work by passing the ARN as a parameter with either --env-vars or --parameter-overrides. So, I ended by leaving the layer ARN hard-coded in my sam template.

Looking forward to see if I am missing something and someone has this working for local invoke as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try other SAM CLI version ?

I got the same error message for SAM CLI version `1.21.1` but not `1.29.0`. I POC via SAM container image `public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs14.x` on local machine (macOS) :

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# SAM_VERSION=1.21.1
SAM_VERSION=1.29.0

CONTAINER=public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs14.x:$SAM_VERSION
EXEC_DIR=/path/to/sam
TARGET_FUNCTION=YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME

docker run \
--rm -it $CONTAINER \
sam --version

docker run \
--env SAM_CLI_TELEMETRY=0 \
--env-file $EXEC_DIR/.env \
-v $EXEC_DIR/functions:/functions \
--rm -it $CONTAINER \
sh -c "cd /functions/$TARGET_FUNCTION && sam build"
```

SAM CLI requires AWS credential, you need to provide environment variables below, ex. my `.env` file :

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=YOUR_TARGET_REGION
AWS_REGION=YOUR_TARGET_REGION
```

and don't forget create IAM that allows `iam:ListPolicy` :

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUsersToPerformUserActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListPolicies"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

##### **Result**

[image]

[image]